# python SQL Server query error

Tags: python, database

My syntax seems to be correct

```
  cursor.execute ("UPDATE us SET USERNAME=Zuhair WHERE USNUM=%s " % (  self.recordnum))

  cnxn.commit()
```

---

When I enter a number, code works, but if used literal data, display my message telling me this

```
42s22 - sql server invalid column name
```

Comment: have your tried without using capital letters oon your query? using username=Zuhair and usnum? And you should add the ; after %s

Answer (score 0):

SQL used single quotes (`'`) to denote string literals. Assuming `Zuhair` isn't a column name, but a string literal of the username you with to set, you should surround it with quotes:

```
cursor.execute ("UPDATE us SET USERNAME='Zuhair' WHERE USNUM=%s " % (  self.recordnum))
```